# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)2n}}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)2n}}\right).$$

I have computed 
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}-a_n & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n+1)(2n+2)}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}\\
            & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(2n+1)}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right).
\end{align*}
Now I'm stuck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint**: $$\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2n-1)(2n)}}$$

$$<\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n-1}$$ and use $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n})=\ln 2$

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

The hint provided by Chinnapparaj R is the key point, to evaluate the bounding sum we can use that

$$\frac1n+\frac1{n+1}+\ldots+\frac1{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}=\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac kn}$$

which is a [Riemann's sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2972643/505767).