# Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{(n + 1)(n+2)}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n(2n + 1)}} = \ln 2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms

To be honest, I don't have much ideas on how to prove it. I only had an idea of using inequation $\frac{1}{n + 1} < \ln(1 + 1/n) < \frac{1}{n}$. But for sure it doesn't give us good approximation.

Comment: I assume there's supposed to be a square root in the last term there?

Comment: Impossible.  Left side is algebraic, right side transcendental.  Do you mean a limit as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: This has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2973156/42969.

Comment: @JohnBarber Thank you for noticing typo!

Comment: This is certainly a Riemann sum.

Comment: This could help maybe. Put $$S_n=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(n + 1)(n+2)}} + \cdots + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2n(2n + 1)}}$$ One has $$\frac{1}{n+1}\lt \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}\lt\frac 1n$$ so $$\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+1}\lt S_n\lt\frac 1n+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}$$