# Evaluate the limit for a function defined on [0,1]

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

The limit is a Riemann sum

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{i^4}{n^5}+\frac{i}{n^2} \right)$$
$\delta x=\frac{1}{n}$, so I distribute it to the terms to get

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{i^4}{n^6}+\frac{i}{n^3}  \right)$$
Now that they have similar denominators I multiply $\frac{i}{n^3}\cdot(n^3)$ to get
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{i^4}{n^6}+\frac{2i}{n^6}  \right)$$

Combining the terms I get $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{2i^4}{n^6}\right)$$
Knowing that $i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ I split up the $i^4$ into$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2}{n^6}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right)+ \left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\right)$$
Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that by [**Riemann sum**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2972643/505767)

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{i^4}{n^5}+\frac{i}{n^2} \right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{i^4}{n^4}+\frac{i}{n} \right)=\int_0^1(x^4+x) dx$$

As an alternative refer to [**Faulhaber's formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).